# stopped a service but outgoing port still exists on netstat -aon

Tags: port, tcp, windows-media-player

bit more detail....

I have a port, specifically port 2869 for Windows Media Player Network Sharing Service that uses UPnP port 2869, however even when turning off all the sharing possibilities I can think of, and stopping the service from the Services list, as well as stopping SSDP Discovery and then adding registry keys, when I open WMP the port still opens itself on cmd, 'netstat -aon'.

The only way I have managed to use the program without the port being opened is by running WMP in Offline mode, File > Offline mode, which then doesn't discover the "Other libraries" on the network, but also limits the functionality of said program for Internet streaming etc.

Am I missing anything stupid or is there no way this port can be closed fully whilst still using the program functionally.

TCP Port 2869 - WMP Network Sharing Services
Opens port when program start, closes port upon application close.
Windows 7
WMP 12

Comment: have you tried stopping the UPNP Host (Vista) or UPNP Device Host (win7) service?

Comment: i thought about that, but then surely this would have a detrimental effect on all other upnp devices attached to the computer?

Answer (score 0):

upnp is a huge security risk and googling will yell you to turn it odf if you havebthe ability to forward ports it is unnecessary. upnp is not thw same as pnp which runs hardware devices.. upnp is 100% a networking service and disabling it will neither stop you from using the network nor affect anything but the security of your system for the better. as I've said so long as you can forward ports you can overcome shuttering upnp

Comment: What exactly are the security risks? Any references to check?